# Disable Buttons according to logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, visibility

I am accepting a userID and want to check if there is any Project Owners with the same ID. If there exists a Project Owner I should only have the "Move Down" Button Enabled and all other buttons disabled. If there exists an admin all buttons are enabled other than the first move up and the last move down. 
I want to disable all the buttons other than in which the POwner is same as the userID ! (if the POwner is same as UserID only move down button should be enabled.

```
 public void Repeater1_ItemDatabound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            String userID = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
            if (setvisibility(userID) == true) //Check if the person is Admin all buttons work 
            {

                if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
                {
                    Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
                    b.Enabled = false;
                }

                DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                DataTable result = view.ToTable();
                if (e.Item.ItemIndex == (result.Rows.Count) - 1)
                {
                    Button b2 = e.Item.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
                    b2.Enabled = false;
                }

            }
            else // Check if Project Owner (POwner exists) Check if userID exists in POwner
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ctd_priority_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select POwner from Projects WHERE POwner = @userid", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userID);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: that has absolutely nothin to do with asp-classic

Comment: I want to disable all the buttons other than in which the POwner is same as the userID !

Answer (score 0):

Create (local) boolean variables for your 2 possible roles

```
bool isAdmin;
bool isProjectOwner;
```

and determine their values **before** going about to enable/disable your buttons.

```
isAdmin = setvisibility(userID);
//isProjectOwner // create a similar method to setvisibility() for your project owner
```

Now you can toggle your buttons visibility simply by assigning or negating your users role states

```
...
if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
{
    Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
    // IS NOT admin AND IS project owner will set .Enabled = true
    b.Enabled = (!isAdmin && isProjectOwner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable **all** the buttons inside a repeater item template then try calling this method at the point you want to disable the controls:

```
private static void DisableButtonControls(RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in e.Item.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Button)
            {
                control.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

To enable the down button after all buttons have been disabled you can do:

```
Button downButton = e.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
if (downButton != null)
{
    downButton.Visible = false;
}
```

A good rule of thumb is that whenever you use the 'as' keyword to convert types check that the returned object is not null before you use it.

Comment: and what if I want only the Down Button enabled if POWner matches the UserID ?